# Выполнение макроса, имя которого записано текстовой строкой

Tags: excel, vba

Есть строка, нужно выполнить макрос, записанный в строке.
Пишу **Evaluate(S + "()")** – макрос вызывается ДВАЖДЫ. Если скобки убрать, то вообще не вызывается.
В чём причина и как сделать правильно?

```
Public Sub Test()
    [A1] = [A1] + 1
End Sub
 
Public Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
    Dim S As String
    S = "Test"
    Evaluate (S + "()")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем так извращаться с *Evaluate*? Есть же метод, заточенный для запуска макросов или вызова функций:

```
Public Sub Test()
    [A1] = [A1] + 1
End Sub
 
Public Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
    Dim S As String
    
    S = "Test"
    Application.Run S
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно справке, `Evaluate` конвертирует имя в объект либо значение. Насчёт иных применений ничего не сказано. Процедура `Test` - не объект, и она не имеет значения. И спрашивать, почему недокументированное применение работает не так, как хочется - бессмысленно.

```
Public Function Test()
    Test = [A1] + 1
End Function
 
Public Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
    Dim S As String
    S = "Test"
    [A1] = Evaluate(S & "()")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, а вызвать макрос как-то ещё можно по имени в строке? Мне не нужна запись именно в ячейку A1, мне нужно выполнить макрос (по имени в строке, а если точнее, то это имя записано в ячейке).

Comment: Вообще, всё равно странно, потому что даже в вашем примере функция всё равно вызывается дважды. А если эта функция изменяет какой-то объект? Скажем, `[A1] = [A1] + 1: Test = [A1]`.

Comment: @EugeneKrasnikov *в вашем примере функция всё равно вызывается дважды.* У меня она выполняется однократно. *А если эта функция изменяет какой-то объект?* Даже мой код - это недокументированное использование.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
`ActiveSheet.Evaluate(S + "()+0")`
ActiveSheet (в отличие от Application) выполняет выражение единожды, а чтобы сделать его выражением, добавляем ноль.